# Drop duplicate rows, but keep the union of their data

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame like this:

```
pd.DataFrame([
    [1, None, 'a'],
    [1, 3.3, None],
    [2, 1.7, 'c']
], columns=['unique_id', 'x', 'target'])
```

I want to drop one of the rows where `unique_id` is `1`, but take the union of their values. That is, I want to produce this:

```
pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 3.3, 'a'],
    [2, 1.7, 'c']
], columns=['unique_id', 'x', 'target'])
```

Can this be done efficiently in Pandas?

Assume this data frame has between 10k and 100k rows, with maybe 10% being duplicates I want to eliminate. There will only be 2 or 3 duplicates of each `unique_id`.

Edit: when both rows have disagreeing entries, just taking the first one is fine in my case. But I'm open to solutions where, e.g. both values are collected in a list.

Comment: Is it all but one `None` values in rows with similar `unique_id`?

Comment: This is still ambiguous.  What if there are two valid values?  It would seem to me that the union would be a collection of both?  If so, what kind of collection?  A `set`, `list`, `tuple`?  If not, how do you choose among them?  The `first`, `last`, random?

Comment: @piRSquared either first or last would be fine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This gives the result for your example. It takes the first non-Nan value for each column, in each group.

```
df.groupby("unique_id", as_index=False).first()
```

Comment: I didn't know about `first`, that looks like it does the job.

Answer (score 1):

Use `groupby` and `first`:

```
df.groupby('unique_id').first()
```